# How to search for string within another string?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a simple word search program.

I have successfully opened an external file that contains the grid of the word search. I also have successfully opened a file that contains the words that are to be searched for. I have stored every line of the grid in a list and every word from the file in a list called `words[]`.

I am attempting to search for the words in each line of the grid. My code currently does not search for the word in each line of the grid.

```
gridlines_horizontal = []
gridlines_vertical = []
words = []
not_found = []
found_words = {}

def puzzle(fname) :
    print ""

    for line in f :
        gridlines_horizontal.append(line)

    for line in gridlines_horizontal :
        print line,

    for item in zip(*(gridlines_horizontal[::-1])):
        gridlines_vertical.append(item)
```

Here I am trying to get each word in `words[]` one at a time and see if the word is in any of the lines of the word search grid. If the word is present in any of the lines I am then trying to print the word. The code currently does not do this.

```
def horizontal_search(word,gridlines_horizontal) :
    x = 0
    for line in gridlines_horizontal :
        if words[0] in line or words[0] in line[::-1]:
            found_words.update({words[0]:" "})
            print words[0]
        else :
            not_found.append(words)

        x = x + 1

def vertical_search(word,gridlines_vertical):
    x = 0
    for line in gridlines_vertical:
        if words[x] in line or words[x] in line[::-1]:
            print words[0]
            found_words.update({words[x]:" "})
        else:
            not_found.append(words[x])

        x = x + 1

while True:
    try:  
        fname = input("Enter a filename between double quotation marks: ")
        with open(fname) as f:
            puzzle(fname)

    break

except IOError as e :
    print""
    print("Problem opening file...")

print ""        

while True:
    try:  
        fname2 = input("Enter a filename for your words between double quotation marks: ")
        with open(fname2) as f:
            for line in f:
                words.append(line)

            """ line in words:
                line = lin   """   

    break

except IOError as e :
    print("")
    print("Problem opening file...")
```

Comment: You mean like a word search puzzle? Can you show some example input and the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple mistakes in your code:

 - You aren't being consistent in using words[x], in your code you would want to replace every words[0] with words[x] **BUT**

 - this isn't necessary because you can use nested 'for' loops.

So for horizontal search:

```
def horizontal_search(words,gridlines_horizontal):
    for word in words:
        for line in gridlines_horizontal:
            if word in line or word in line[::-1]:
                found_words.update({word : " "})
                print(word)
                break
            else:
                not_found.append(word)
```

Comment: Did you read the question :)? OP already knows this; the question is something else.

Comment: I will better explain my answer and adapt it to this question. Thank you for pointing out it seems to not be answering @Cyphase

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [find](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)?

```
a = 'this is a string'
b = 'string'

if (a.find(b) > -1):
    print 'found substring in string'
else:
    print 'substring not found in string'
```

[Live](https://ideone.com/9U4KCY) demo of above code

**EDIT:**

I am not sure if its a typo, but you are passing `word` as parameter instead of `words`

```
def horizontal_search(word,gridlines_horizontal) :
x = 0                   ^----------------------------------  
for line in gridlines_horizontal :                        |
    if words[0] in line or words[0] in line[::-1]:        |
         ^-- see here  <------------not matching here -----
```

Similar issue with `def vertical_search(words,gridlines_vertical)` :

Comment: @Cyphase I did. But, we cannot just solve the code ;). That's why I gave a generic example.

Comment: OP is already doing `x_str in y_str` to search on that level; this is just another way of doing something the OP is already doing perfectly fine. In fact, since even your code is not using the index, I think using `in` is better.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm taking a second look, your code is wrong. The condition will always be `True` _unless_ `b` is found at index `0`, which isn't even a time it should be `False`.

Comment: @Cyphase. Oops. Thanks :)

Comment: I have tried using in and find but it still does not appear to be able to find out if the words are in the grid